# UV, edit edge that is connected to other edge

Tags: uv

[image]I would like to straighten (or do any operation) upper edge, but it auto selects the bottom edge as well, in Vertex and Edge modes.

Is there a way to only select the upper edge? Btw, the edge is split already.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot?

Comment: Added the picture. 
I found that UV Sync Selection toggle (Arrows, top left) was on and that was auto connecting two edges. 
However that is not ideal. I always want to sync to the viewport, while be able to move edges separately.

Comment: How is the edge split? You mean it is marked as seam? But that's not actually splitting an edge. If the edge was split, you would have two edges, each with its own vertices. But the vertices you are selecting there on the top are the same which you have on the bottom. They are only shown duplicated for the UV layout because they are the top vertices of one face and the bottom vertices of another face. When you use _UV Sync Selection_, vertices selected in the UV map are the same selected in the mesh in the 3D viewport - but you cannot select and unselect vertices at the same time on a mesh.

Comment: Maybe disable the UV Sync Selection option of the UV Editor and select all the mesh in the 3D view?